# Customize checkout/cart/ Magento process

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I need to introduce custom fields and design in the checkout/cart process. The fields includes information about different shipping cost for different regions. Somebody could give me info about it please?

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is to have **Estimate Shipping & Tax** option. Magento already provides it on the cart page.

Below is the screenshot for the same

[image]

This will give you Shipping And Tax based on different countries and states.

Also check if shipping method is enabled from backend.

If everything seems okay and you still don't see your block then try the below code in your **local.xml** to include the block on cart page

```
<checkout_cart_index>
  <reference name="content">
     <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template= "checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>
  </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```